# scrapy crawl will execute all spider's code outside of the function in one project ,how to solve this?

Tags: python, scrapy

```
class spider1(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "spider1"
    client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
    db=client.db
    col=db.col
    col.drop()
    col=db.col
    def parse():

class spider2(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "spider2"
    client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
    db=client.db
    col=db.col
    def parse():
```

spider1 i want  to flush all the data,and write,and spider2 i want to update the data,but when i run spider2,the database will execute drop,i've asked in irc ,someone told me that ,scrapy crawl will execute all the code outside of the function.

how to solve this problem?  I've tried several ways:
1,use pipeline,but i want to store the data ,meantime  export an json file(this i diy my jsonpipeline,but you cant use more than one pipeline at the same time).I've found no solution.
2,use the __init__function.
  i tried like this:

```
  spider3(scrapy.Spider):
  def __init__(self):
     super(spider3,self).__init__()
     print 'test function'
```

but,it dont work.

i have searched all the time,to solve this,but found no solution.

hope someone can help me with this,many thanks!
from a scrapy beginner

Comment: what do you mean by _"use the __init__function. i tried like this... but,it dont work"_. The following simple 2 spider example worked for me:
https://gist.github.com/redapple/462b9102d8611e986143 .  It printed either `ExampleSpider1::__init__()` or `ExampleSpider2::__init__()` depending on `scrapy crawl example1` or `scrapy crawl example2` but not both.

Comment: thank you .  I made a low level mistake.  0.0"       the  init  function works

Comment: only i  compare your code,i  find the mistaks

Comment: does it mean your issue is fixed?

Comment: yes  very fixed..thanks a  lot

Comment: and  how  to  use headers in crawlspider not in middleware in one spider?   I buy your CRAWLERA plans...